# How to writte a raster plot?

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I'm using pytorch on google colab.
I've got a tensor matrix below, this is the example, and actually the matrix size is about 50 neurons and 30,000~50,000 time.

```
a= torch.tensor([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
                 [0., 1., 0., 1., 0.]])
```

each of values are,

```
a= torch.tensor([[Neuron1(t=1), N2(t=1), N3(t=1), N4(t=1), N5(t=1)],
                 [N1(t=2), N2(t=2), N3(t=2), N4(t=2), N5(t=2)],
                 [N1(t=3), N2(t=3), N3(t=3), N4(t=3), N5(t=3)]])
```

and 1 means that neuron fire, 0 means not fire.
So `Neuron5(t=2)`, `Neuron2(t=3)` and `Neuron4(t=3)` are firing.
Then, I want to make a raster plot or scatter plot like below using this matrix,
The dots show the firing neuron.

neuron number
1|
2|          *
3|
4|          *
5|__ *_____time
    1  2  3

What would be the best python code to do this?
I have no idea now.
Thank you for reading.

Comment: I'd say convert the result to pure numpy array, then ploting the result using pyplot's imshow https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html?highlight=imshow#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow

Comment: Thank you and sorry for late because I wrote that code. I'll put it on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a= torch.tensor([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
                 [0., 1., 0., 1., 0.]],device='cuda')
plt.scatter(*torch.where(a.cpu()))
```

Answer (score 1):

High resolution version, derived from Mr Gil's code.

```
a= ~~~a huge torch.tensor (50 neurons and 30,000 time)~~~

fig = plt.figure(facecolor="w", figsize=(300,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(*torch.where(a.cpu()),
                      s=0.05[![enter image description here][1]][1],
                      c="black",
                      linewidths="0")
plt.savefig("rascatter.png",format="png", dpi=120)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two answers here. Thank you very much everyone.

One is Mr Gil Pinsky and the other is Mr tgrandje.
Mr Gil's code is on above. Thank you.

And here is the code I wrote based on Mr tgrandje's advice.

```
a=input_list
b = a.to('cpu').detach().numpy().copy()
c=b.T
raster = plt.imshow(c,cmap="Greys",aspect=1)
# plt.show
plt.savefig("raster.png", format="png", dpi=900)
```